# why doesn't the ambient light illuminate my whole model?

Tags: three.js

I found this related question but I'm using a MeshLambertMaterial and my question is about ambient light:
[Why doesn't my directional light affect the whole scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219248/why-doesnt-my-directional-light-affect-the-whole-scene)

My model is about 150 feet long and the ambient light only illuminates about the front half of it. I've added point lights along the way but I still can't see the back of the model.

Why doesn't the ambient light illuminate the whole model?

Here is the model:
http://julio.broomstones.com/webgl/sheet/webgl_sheet.html
If you zoom in with the middle button you will see the end of the sheet. I've placed globes at the point lights. They do help but not enough.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in fog and camera settings. Try change [`far`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Scenes/Fog) propertie of `fog` and [`far`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/PerspectiveCamera) propertie of `camera` (reducing these values to reduce the visible area). For example:

```
var far_clip_plane = 4000;
...
scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x000000, 140, 2000 );
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/gqpLxuf9/ ]